# How are Handlers and Runnables used in Android Programming?

Tags: android-handler

What are Handlers and Runnables used for in Android programming. What is the relationship between them? Also, how does Handlers differ from Threads?

Answer (score 0):

Difference is minor, both are executed in a separate execution flow, i.e. have their own execution contexts. In Android programming, certain instructions should be executed in non-UI thread. For example, networking. That's where Runnable and Handler come to mind. The only important difference is that Handler is supposed to be executed when some asynchronous event happens, whereas Runnable is executed whenever programmer wants it to be executed

Answer (score 0):

No Difference Between them .Handler is a subclass of thread class.

```
Handler
```

allows send messages between two threads in a safe manner, that means that sending thread puts message into destination thread queue, and this destination queue will process this message in its appropriate time.

```
Runnable
```

this is an interface that you implement, in implementation you put logic you want to execute on some thread. You can actually use Runnable also in non thread related places. Lots of Java apis actually use Runnable, not only Thread's. You can post Runnable using handler, or you can use it with executors. Runnables are nice because you can implement them in a form of anonymous implementation.